# Mapping between DB2 XML CLOB data type and DB2 JDBC types are keep changing as upgrading to different JDBC versions

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

We were using com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4 `v10.1` and recently we have upgraded it with the `V11.1.4 FP5` driver for the `z/OS Db2 systems`. When we were using com.ibm.db2.jcc.db2jcc4 `v10.1` the equivalent JDBC java class for DB2 XML CLOB was `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ne` and now after upgrading it with `V11.1.4 FP5` driver now, it changed to `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.db`. However in latest version `v11.5 M7 FP0` it's again changed to `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dc`.

The question is: If someone using extracting the old DB2 XML CLOB data type from newer JDBC driver then how can we extract an older clob instance which might represents as `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ne` from new `V11.1.4 FP5` driver as this has been replaced with `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.db`.

Comment: There is no such a data type as `DB2 XML CLOB`. Why don't you use the `java.sql.SQLXML` data type as described at the [XML data retrieval in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=applications-xml-data-retrieval-in-jdbc) link which is the same for both Db2 jcc drivers? Do you have any problems with the approach described there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to use the `java.sql.SQLXML` data type as described at the [XML data retrieval in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=applications-xml-data-retrieval-in-jdbc) link instead of direct use of these internal driver classes.